# Need to pass variable parameter through Batch script file

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have the properties.txt file containing sql scripts, where I need to pass the variable value through windows batch file.

Issue scenario query is:

```
SELECT a,b,c 
FROM dual 
where TO_CHAR(EXPECTED_RECOGNITION_DATE,'MM-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'MM-YYYY')
```

I would like to pass value for through variable parameter such that this function: `TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'MM-YYYY')` will provide dynamic output as:"12-2016" & in next month it will be "01-2017"

Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product specific functionality there...

Comment: I think you can`t evaluate variables in SQL expression loaded from file. You have to put your SQL expression on windows command line. Example from my SQLite usage:

sqlite3.exe database\myDB.db "SELECT a,b,c FROM dual WHERE date='%date%' AND time='%time%';"

or if you need preserve non-english characters encoding, use this:

echo SELECT a,b,c FROM dual WHERE date='%date%' AND time='%time%'; | sqlite3 database\myDB.db

Answer (score 0):

Admitting we are in January 2017, to compute the "12-2016" thing in batch, you can do :

```
::get current month and year
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
  set month=%%b
  set year=%%c
)

::get the previous month
if "%month" NEQ "01" (
  set /A month=%month%-1
) else (
  set month=12
  set /A year=%year%-1
)

::if things like "1-2017" aren't valid, you can add a zero
set month=00%month%
set month=%month:~-2%

::compute the final date
set date=%month%-%year%

::now call your request like @user2956477 said, using %date%
::(don't forget to add quotes if needed)
```

if you feel disturbed with the "for" syntax, take a look at the man (type `for /?` in your terminal). Take a look in particular at the `/F` options.